# Ubuntu Server 18.04 Destination Host Unreachable

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, internet

I installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 and configured the network:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.95.227/24
      gateway4: 192.168.95.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

The router is a Cisco with DHCP disabled, everything is working fine, all other 50+ computers connecting to the internet, so not a problem with the router/gateway.

Now when I ping 192.168.95.1 or any other IP with a working computer its working, but when I ping any external IP like 8.8.8.8 I get Destination Host Unreachable

Now the Server is locally connected within the network, but no internet access.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `ping -c 5 8.8.8.8` and `host www.ebay.com`.

Comment: Also show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces`.

Answer (score 2):

**.yaml**

Set your .yaml to the following, keeping the indentation, and no tabs:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses: [192.168.95.227/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.95.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot` # you must reboot

**ethernet cabling**

The ethernet interface is only running at 100Mb, and this usually means a cabling problem. Assure that you are using quality cat 5e or cat 6, or better, cabling. Reverify 1000Mb operation by viewing the `sudo lshw -C network` command, and observe the SIZE/speed parameter.

Verify that all network hardware, switches/hubs/router/etc, are gigabit capable and functioning correctly.

Comment: Ok sorry for being late. I tried them all and the same thing here. I will add all the output in the next comments.

Comment: $ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for medk:
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5754 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1a:a0:b1:6b:07
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz

Comment: capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=full firmware=5754-v3.15 ip=192.168.95.234 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:25 memory:dfaf0000-dfafffff

Comment: $ ping -c 5 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.95.234 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.95.234 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.95.234 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.95.234 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.95.234 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +5 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4048ms
pipe 3

Comment: $ host www.ebay.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
medk@squid2:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown

Comment: $ sudo netplan --debug generate
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/lib/netplan/generate']
** (generate:2184): DEBUG: 09:31:09.046: Processing input file /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml..
** (generate:2184): DEBUG: 09:31:09.046: starting new processing pass
** (generate:2184): DEBUG: 09:31:09.046: Processing input file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml..

Comment: ** (generate:2184): DEBUG: 09:31:09.046: starting new processing pass
** (generate:2184): DEBUG: 09:31:09.046: enp3s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:2184): DEBUG: 09:31:09.046: Configuration is valid
** (generate:2184): DEBUG: 09:31:09.046: Generating output files..
** (generate:2184): DEBUG: 09:31:09.047: NetworkManager: definition enp3s0 is not for us (backend 1)

Comment: Sorry this is confusing as in comments it doesn't keep the formatting.

Comment: @medk Thanks for the info. However, as you notice, putting that kind of data into comments completely looses the formatting... that's why I said "edit your question", and there, once pasted, you select the pasted text and then click the {} icon to keep the formatting human-readable.

Comment: @medk  In trying to read the comments, the only thing that I see is that the ethernet interface is only running at 100Mb, and this usually means a cabling problem. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6, or better, cabling? Please describe EXACTLY the ethernet cabling from the server to the modem.

Comment: @medk Why would you run the Cisco without DHCP?

Comment: @medk Did you install my .yaml exactly as shown? My guess is no, correct?

Comment: @medk Do you have "Access Control" enabled in the Cisco?

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't think this error lies within the Ubuntu System.
Can you check on your Cisco router if the ICMP packages arrive there and are routed correctly?

You should check if your router blocks icmp or more for your specific IP address.

You should also check if you have given the `192.168.95.227` address to two different devices.

You can check that with a ping to the `.227` and shutting down the Server. 
When the ping still answers, you have two clients with the same IP.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I changed .227 to .234 which is free for sure and still the same thing. For the icmp I have another Ubuntu Server 16.04 and Squid and it's working fine except that I'm not using the /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml as in the other server the file is empty.

Comment: @medk The older 16.04 server doesn't use netplan, but is probably configured in `/etc/network/interfaces`.